# Можно ли в r-строке шаблоне с префиксом f указать вхождение подстроки в фигурных скобках?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, re

Я пишу на python 3.8 и использую библиотеку re, создав строку-шаблон мне показалось удобным вставить в этот шаблон другой который я уже использовала, для этого мне и нужен префикс f. Но в другом месте шаблона было указано количество вхождений подстроки в фигурных скобках и теперь код выдает ошибку потому что думает что там переменная. Можно ли как то экранировать такие случаи?

UPD: В моем случае отличным решением оказалось экранирование путем добавления еще одних фигурных скобок - {{2}}

```
username_template = r'\w(\.?\w+)*'

link_template = fr'^https://www\.instagram\.com/{username_template}/(\?hl=[a-z]{2})?$'
```

Comment: Если нашли решение самостоятельно, лучше добавить ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, так навскидку, можно просто завершить в проблемном месте предыдущую строку и тут же начать новую, обычную строку, они сами склеятся в одну строку:

```
link_template = fr'^https://www\.instagram\.com/{username_template}/(\?hl=[a-z]''{2})?$'
                                                                               ^^
```

А если там будут какие-то спецсимволы и нужна всё же `r`-строка, то можно и новую `r`-строку в том месте начать:

```
link_template = fr'^https://www\.instagram\.com/{username_template}/(\?hl=[a-z]'r'{2})?$'
                                                                               ^^^
```